# Using boost::shared_ptr within inheritance hierarchy

Tags: c++, inheritance, boost

Imagine the following situation:

```
class IAlarm : public boost::enable_shared_from_this<IAlarm>  {
   boost::shared_ptr<IAlarm> getThisPointerForIAlarm() {
      return shared_from_this();
   }

   void verifyThis(int); // called by Device
};

class Alarm : public IAlarm {
   Alarm( boost::shared_ptr< Device >  attachedDevice){
      attachedDevice->attachAlarm(this->getThisPointerForIAlarm());
   }

   void sendAlarm(){
      attachedDevice->Alarm();
   } 

};

class Device {
   attachAlarm( boost::shared_ptr< IAlarm > ia){
      this->alarm=ia;
   }
};
```

I want to attach an Alarm to a Device. Alarm and Device aren't allowed to know about each other (this would end up in circular dependency). So that's why I use the Interface Class IAlarm. Finally I want to be able  to attach several alarms on to one device. The alarms can access the device they are attached to and the devices can start verification on the attached Alarms

Everything compiles nice. But if I try to attach an Alarm to a Device I get the following:

```
boost::shared_ptr<Device> ptrDevice(new Device());
boost::shared_ptr<IAlarm> ptrAlarm(new Alarm( ptrDevice ));

    terminate called after throwing an instance of 'boost::exception_detail::clone_impl<boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<boost::bad_weak_ptr> >'

  what():  tr1::bad_weak_ptr
```

What's exactly the problem? This setup worked more or less before using `boost::shared_ptr` with references and pure pointers. Is it possible to get this work with `boost:shared_ptr`?

Comment: You're not showing the actual code so it isn't easy to tell anything about it.

Comment: @KayEss: I agree.  There's too much missing here.

Comment: how is "alarm" declared? Why do you use this->alarm rather than simply "alarm"?

Comment: Device is not supposed to be derived from IAlarm. 
The actual code would be to much to post. But the given Code fragments more or less reflect the Problem. 
Alarm is declared as follwos:
boost::shared_ptr<IAlarm> ptrAlarm(new Alarm( ptrDevice ));
Would this->alarm=xy be different to alarm=xy ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The call to `shared_from_this()` is only valid if it is called on a dynamically allocated object that is owned by a `shared_ptr` (See the requirements [listed in the docs](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/libs/smart_ptr/enable_shared_from_this.html)). This means that there must exist a `shared_ptr` that owns the object, else `shared_from_this()` will not work.

Especially this means that you can't (successfully) call `shared_from_this()` in the constructor, since the object is just being constructed and is not yet owned by any `shared_ptr` instance.

To work around it you best move the code that attaches the alarm from the constructor to a separate method that gets called after the object is completely constructed:

```
boost::shared_ptr<Alarm> a(new Alarm());
a->attach(attachedDevice);
```